# Negative of "everybody said something"

Tags: sentence-construction

What should be the negative of the sentence?

> Everyone said something.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @BillJ nobody said something ... is  it correct?

Comment: Nobody said anything?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey are you sure about "anything"

Comment: Do you mean the 'opposite' to say 'all were silent'?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why a negative of this sentence would be required. Better to actually describe the situation. Things that are unlike "everyone said something" in a similar context would include;

> Nobody said anything

> One person said something

Comment: its not even clear to me also but i have to do it because it is one of the question of my university exam

Answer (score 0):

The answer is “nobody said anything.”

You use “anything” because it is in the context of “nobody,” same as you would usually say “Is anyone there?” instead of “Is someone there?” The prefix “any-“ implies a context of nobody/nothing.